# How do I tell if my current thread is the UI thread in WinUI 3?

Tags: c++, winui-3, winui

I'm working on some library code for WinUI 3 applications, and I want to assert that certain functions are called on the UI thread.

I know how to [check if the current thread is the UI thread for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108513/how-do-i-tell-if-my-current-thread-is-the-ui-thread), but how do I do that for WinUI 3? CoreDispatcher and CoreWindow [aren't used the same in WinUI 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/winui3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DispatcherQueue::GetForCurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) instead of [the `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher` method for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63376211/788168). It will return a dispatcher instance if you're on the UI thread, & `nullptr` otherwise:

```cpp
bool IsUIThread()
{
    return nullptr != winrt::Microsoft::UI::Dispatching::DispatcherQueue::GetForCurrentThread();
}
```

Comment: Will this work both for UWP applications and WinUI3?

Comment: That's an interesting question---I don't know offhand. But I think the `Microsoft::UI` namespace is unique to WinUI 3, so it won't be available for UWP or WinUI 2 apps.