# How do I know if a key is pressed in WinUI 3/WinAppSDK (CoreWindow.GetKeyState alternatives)?

Tags: c++, xaml, winui-3

In my old UWP apps, I could check a keyboard key's state in my handlers, like this:

```cpp
void MyControl::UserControl_KeyDown(winrt::IInspectable const& /*sender*/, winrt::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    if (e.Key() == winrt::VirtualKey::F6)
    {
        const auto isShiftPressed = winrt::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(winrt::VirtualKey::Shift) & winrt::CoreVirtualKeyStates::Down;
        // ...
    }
}
```

But [`winrt::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()` returns `null` in WinUI 3](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4225). How do I get keyboard states in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official docs ([Windows Runtime APIs not supported in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#core-unsupported-classes)) recommend [`InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.input.inputkeyboardsource.getkeystateforcurrentthread?view=windows-app-sdk-1.5) instead:

> [...]Instead of the [**GetKeyState**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getkeystate?view=winrt-22621) method, use the [**InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.input.inputkeyboardsource.getkeystateforcurrentthread?view=windows-app-sdk-1.5) method provided by WinUI 3.

```cpp
void MyControl::UserControl_KeyDown(winrt::IInspectable const& /*sender*/, winrt::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    if (e.Key() == winrt::VirtualKey::F6)
    {
        const auto isShiftPressed = winrt::InputKeyboardSource::GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(winrt::VirtualKey::Shift) & winrt::CoreVirtualKeyStates::Down;
        // ...
    }
}
```

See [my similar question about getting the UI thread in WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813108/788168).

Comment: Albeit a C# project, this is also the API we settled on in the WinUI Gallery: https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/4f49456f6b21594e551dadea7142d47187eacf51/WinUIGallery/Helper/NavigationHelper.cs#L258-L262